# Standing in front of Shaliach Tzibbur

Tags: halacha, tefilla, sources-mekorot, chazzan-prayer-leader

When I learned Chelek א of Mishna Brura, I remember having read somewhere that even if one can stand in front of a Mispalel only 4 ammot forward, in front of a Shaliach Tzibbur he can never stand in front even further than 4 ammot.

Does anyone know if this is right or know the source?

Comment: Don't see it anywhere in סימן קב - שלא להפסיק כנגד המתפלל